# How can I add a custom warning to Java files in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to add a custom warning message (i.e. add an entry to the Warnings section of the Problems tab) for `.java` files in Eclipse.

While I've found information (here and elsewhere) on creating plugins and using markers, I haven't yet found anything which talks about extending the "problem-finding" process.  Most of the articles I've found don't discuss *when* to create markers, only *how*, and those that do assume that I'm interested in attaching them to a custom build step or custom editor, neither of which seems appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

How can I create a warning which functions like those available via Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings?

Comment: I don't know what kind of warnings you want to add. But [Checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net) might help. It allows you to define rules to check your source code for problems

Comment: What are you you warning about?

Comment: @ChrisGerken — I'm not completely happy with Eclipse's NLS implementation (if nothing else, it seems perverse to have to mark translation keys as untranslatable; that seems to guarantee every string in the source is marked `NON-NLS`) and want to put together an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a builder might be appropriate for what you want to do.  There's a template in the new plugin wizard that creates everything you need for a builder (ex. business logic).  Since the builder runs every time the file is modified, you can clear the old warning (code generated for you) and add a new warning (code generated for you) if applicable. This also applies when the file is first created.

You could even look through the code and find hard-coded strings and flag them with warnings if you want.

As for the comments marking translation keys in the code today, those are there to guide NLS tools (you probably already knew that). The idea was to write the code first and then go back later and translate.  If a change is made to the code later, the tools can run again and only act on new strings added by the delta.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I have this crazy idea involving recognizing calls to the localizer and ignoring the keys used in them.  :-)

Comment: The AST returned by the JDT java parser ought to have enough detail for that.  Crazy is good.