# How to create a custom Eclipse warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, types, compiler-construction, warnings

There are three types of classes:

- Handler
- Service
- DAO

A handler handles an incoming command an calls a services. The services does caching and calls other services or a DAO. Services and DAOs are singletons.

Is there a way to create a custom warning if a DAO is used in one of the handlers?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764236/how-can-i-add-a-custom-warning-to-java-files-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing with some custom checkstyle rules but... you should rather try to it properly ;)

Create 3 modules (projects in Eclipse). Let Handlers know only about the Services (add a proper dependency to Handlers project) and let Serices know about DAOs (add a DAO project to Services dependencies). This way you will never make a mistake :]