# Enforce no space before array brackets for method return type in Java code

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want to have unified way of declaring arrays in my Java project for method return type.

```
String[] method1() { return null; } // OK

String [] method2() { return null; } // Warn!
```

Is there any check to help me with that? I know about [ArrayTypeStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#ArrayTypeStyle), but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that you also need to warn for `String method2()[] {}`

Comment: @Tunaki, yeah - thanks. and also `String method2()   [] {}`

Comment: maybe this answer can help.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765069/3850595

Comment: Why? More time and money is wasted by computer programmers arguing and obsessing about where and where not to put spaces than I care to think about. I wasted a lot of it myself, until I started running my own business and realised where the money was going. The compiler doesn't care, and the impact on readability could hardly be lower.

Comment: @EJP, that's exactly why I want to automate this and stop any discussion on whitespaces during code review. Person with properly configured and decent IDE that does reformatting of code before each commit should never experience violation of such rule, so it won't consume any time for them.